# parsing response POST data from curl_exec call

Tags: php, post, curl, https

I have the following code block which connects out to a secure service (payment transaction gateway), passes in some fields ($postData) and receives a response ($returnValue).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://secure.service.com/data');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
if ($returnValue = curl_exec($ch))
{
    $error = curl_error($ch);
}
```

When I display the contents of $returnValue ... they show as follows:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Approved Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 09:24:15 GMT
>   Connection: close Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 182
>   avs_code=X&cvv2_code=P&status_code=1&processor=TEST&auth_code=999999&settle_amount=2000&settle_currency=USD&trans_id=120741127516&auth_msg=TEST+APPROVED&auth_date=2011-08-10+09:24:15

Is there a method or CURL call that breaks apart this result string into its component parts? or is that something I need to write myself? I need to get the response code (200), the approval/decline part (Approved) and the query string (avs_code ....). I tried looking through the curl_getinfo but that is only getting me the HTTP Response code, not the approval/decline or the query string values.

I'm a novice at PHP so please let me know if I'm missing an obvious method call or CURL parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $header=substr($result,0,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    $body=substr($result,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    curl_close($ch);
```

Than use something like `preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i",$header,$res);`

See [preg_match_all manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: I think you will still have the \r\n\r\n which seperates those 2 according to the http response specs in one of those vars after that substr split.  When doing it this way, you probably want to get rid of those.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php manual, if you don't want to install PECL pecl_http - there are usefull user comments. For example:

```
function http_parse_headers($header) {
    $retVal = array();
    $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match)) {
            $match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
            if (isset($retVal[$match[1]])) {
                $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
            } else {
                $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```

You can parse cookies and post values with http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-parse-cookie.php (or functions in comments) and http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php . HTTP protocol is rather transparent.